# How can I implement auto-scroll into a chat app?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm  making a chat app as a foundation for a sort of forum website, and I want it to automatically scroll to the bottom of the div once a message is sent (and if the user is close to the bottom of it.)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Chat App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chat-container">
        <ul id="messages"></ul>
        <form id="form">
            <input id="input" autocomplete="off" />
        </form>
    </div>

    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
          var socket = io();

          function scrollToBottom() {
              var container = $('#chat-container');
              var scrollHeight = container.prop('scrollHeight');
              var scrollTop = container.scrollTop();
              var containerHeight = container.height();
              if (scrollTop + containerHeight >= scrollHeight - 50) { // 50px offset for tolerance
                  container.scrollTop(scrollHeight);
              }
          }

          socket.on('init', function(messages) {
              messages.forEach(function(message) {
                  const listItem = $('<li>');
                  const username = $('<strong>').text(message.message.split(':')[0] + ':');
                  const msgText = $('<span>').text(message.message.split(':').slice(1).join(':'));
                  listItem.append(username).append('<br>').append(msgText);
                  $('#messages').append(listItem);
              });
              scrollToBottom();
          });

          socket.on('chat message', function(message) {
              const listItem = $('<li>');
              const username = $('<strong>').text(message.message.split(':')[0] + ':');
              const msgText = $('<span>').text(message.message.split(':').slice(1).join(':'));
              listItem.append(username).append('<br>').append(msgText);
              $('#messages').append(listItem);
              scrollToBottom();
          });

          $('#form').submit(function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              var message = $('#input').val();
              if (message) {
                  socket.emit('chat message', message);
                  $('#input').val('');
              }
          });
      });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const socketIo = require('socket.io');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo(server);

const mongoDB = 'MONGODB SERVER REPLACE THIS';
mongoose.connect(mongoDB)
.then(() => console.log('Connected to MongoDB'))
.catch(err => console.error('Error connecting to MongoDB:', err));
mongoose.connect(mongoDB, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

// Define a schema and model for chat messages
const messageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  message: String,
  timestamp: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
const Message = mongoose.model('Message', messageSchema);

// Serve static files from the "public" directory
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

// Function to generate random usernames
function generateRandomUsername() {
    const adjectives = ["Ancient", "Mysterious", "Silent", "Wandering", "Hidden"];
    const nouns = ["Traveler", "Wanderer", "Explorer", "Sage", "Pilgrim"];
    const adjective = adjectives[Math.floor(Math.random() * adjectives.length)];
    const noun = nouns[Math.floor(Math.random() * nouns.length)];
    const number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
    return `${adjective}${noun}${number}`;
}

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    const username = generateRandomUsername();

    // Fetch and emit past messages
    Message.find().sort({ timestamp: 1 }).lean().exec()
    .then(messages => {
      socket.emit('init', messages);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error('Error fetching messages:', err);
    });

    socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
        const fullMessage = `${username}:${msg}`;
        const newMessage = new Message({ message: fullMessage });
        newMessage.save()
        .then(savedMessage => {
            io.emit('chat message', savedMessage);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error('Error saving message:', err);
        });
    });
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

It (obviously) uses MongoDB as a server, I excluded my database here.

I've tried this a couple times and even asked GPT-4 about it, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: I see you already have a `scrollToBottom()` call on `chat message` "event". What's wrong with your current implementation?

Comment: @DiegoD I'm really not sure, I am not experienced at all with JS. It might be because the actual chat part is in a div?

Comment: let's start from scratch: did you code that snippet yourself? do you know what it does? or are you just sharing a random code you copied and asking to add something without knowing it actually already holds an apparent implementation of the feature you asked for in your question?

Comment: the question is: since it seems scrollToBottom happens to look exactly what you asked for, I was wondering what it does so far... since I cannot see it live but you can

Comment: @DiegoD wait nvm i fixed it, i accidentally had it scroll #chat-container instead of #messages. thank you for the help, though.